# feature generation - Aggregating based on certain column values

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, data-science

Im using python to analyze and process a dataset.
I am currently working on generating features but need some expertise.

The data shows tasks that have been performed by trainees.
Tasks can be easy or hard.
Trainees can either assist or complete the task in full.

I want to get aggregates of how may of each difficulty was performed by each trainee, but have not been able to get this as required so far.

Below is a sample of the data & the output im trying to achieve.
Would really appreciate help in getting these aggregates using python.

A link to the raw data in csv format is [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgldA0VQfPV9hMc7-Ewem_V1EMYz6g)

```
Source Data
Name    Task    Difficulty  Involvment  Score
Jim     A1      Easy        Full        80
Jim     A2      Hard        Assist      40
Jim     B6      Easy        Full        10
Jim     D12      Hard       Assist      40
Ann     B6      Easy        Full        70
Ann     A2      Hard        Assist      20
Ann     C7      Hard        Assist      20
Ann     D12      Hard       Full        80
Joe     A2      Hard        Assist      40


Required Output format

Name    OverallScore    CountEasyAssist CountEasyFull   CountHardAssist CountHardFull
Jim     160             0                2                2                0
Ann     190             0                1                2                1
Joe     40              0                0                1                0
```

Comment: `but have not been able to get this as required so far`. Can you show us **[as an edit to your question, with code](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53139784/edit)** your best/latest attempt?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `pd.crosstab`, although this obviously won't be able to aggregate for a column that has no counts in `sample.csv` - e.g. the column, `CountEasyAssist`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample1.csv')

scores = df.groupby('Name')['Score'].sum().to_frame()

df = pd.crosstab([df.Name], [df.Involvment, df.Difficulty])

df = scores.join(df)

df.columns = ['OverallScore', 'CountHardAssist', 'CountEasyFull', 'CountHardFull']
```